# How to handle exceptions when connection to Cassandra fails?

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-flink

I have my Cassandra sink configured as shown below:

```
    ClusterBuilder secureCassandraSinkClusterBuilder = new ClusterBuilder() {
        @Override
        protected Cluster buildCluster(Cluster.Builder builder) {
            return builder.addContactPoints(props.getCassandraClusterUrlAll().split(","))
                    .withPort(props.getCassandraPort())
                    .withAuthProvider(new DseGSSAPIAuthProvider("HTTP"))
                    .build();
    };

    CassandraSink
            .addSink(cassandraObjectStream)
            .setClusterBuilder(secureCassandraSinkClusterBuilder)
            .build()
            .name("Cassandra-Sink");
```

Now when the connection to Cassandra is not configured properly, I get a *NoHostAvailableException* or when the connection unexpectedly drops, I get a *ConnectionTimeOutException*, or sometimes a *WriteTimeoutException*. This ultimately triggers a *JobExecutionException* and the whole Flink job terminates.

Where do I catch these Cassandra exceptions? Where are these thrown? I tried putting a try-catch block around the CassandraSink but that doesn't do it. I want to catch these exceptions and retry connecting to Cassandra in case of a connection time-out or retry writing to Cassandra in case of a write time-out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot try to catch these exceptions using `CassandraSink`.

One way to catch the exceptions like TimeoutException is to implement your own sink for Cassandra, but it may take a lot of time...

Another way is if you run your streaming job, you could set the task retry to more than 1 through `StreamingExecutionEnvironment.setRestartStrategy`, and enable the checkpoint so that the streaming job could continue working based on the last checkpoint. `CassandraSink` supports WAL, so the `EXACTLY_ONCE` can be achieved with checkpoint enabled.